# Icons not visible in QListWidgetItem

Tags: qt, pyqt4

Even after adding the icon in the QListWidgetItem the icon is not appearing.
The following is what I did to have an item with an icon.

`item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon("filename"), "text")`
`listWidget.addItem(item)`

The icon file name is correct (I checked).
Would be grateful if someone helps me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add icon with seticon eg:

```
item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem('text')
item.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('%s/blend.png'%(RESOURCE_PATH)))
```